# Androidstudio can not obtain the version of adb

Tags: windows, adb

The environment is these:
Androidstudio  2.1.1
Window 7
latest android sdk
Then some day when i open the Androidstuio ,it can find any device or emulator, and show the prompt

```
 Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: 
 Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'.
```

I searched the internet,but cannot find a solution.Can anyone help with this?

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKpMI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckly i find the reason.The problem is caused by Tencent PC Manager(version chinese).When the problem happened, Tencent PC Manager is not the latest version,so i upgrade it ,then the problem dismiss.